# How to change the status of the omni-channel chat agent to busy when the agent ends the chat or the user end the chat on the front end?

Tags: apex, trigger, liveagent, omnichannel

Is this possible to do ? I am attaching images below.

[image]

I want the above status to change busy when the agent clicks on end chat (image below).

[image]

Or when the user ends the chat on the front end by clicking on the 'X' like below.

[image]

Comment: Can you state what is the business requirement for setting to busy instead of available when the chat is ended?

Comment: It seems pretty pointless to do in the first place. But the clients want it done if possible. I know it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve that only using Aura component (I think)
You need to combine omniToolkitAPI and conversationToolkitAPI

OmniToolikit API can change statuses (using setServicePresenceStatus function)
conversationToolkitAPI can handle event such as conversationEnding:
CMP File :

```
<aura:attribute name="AllAvailable" type="String"/>
<aura:handler event="lightning:conversationChatEnded" action="{!c.onConversationChatEnded}" />
```

in js controller file :

```
 omniAPI.setServicePresenceStatus({statusId: cmp.get("v.Available")}).then(function(result) {
          //there are some info we get in the response such as statusId and channels           
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
         });
```

In my example I already have the id of the agent status i want stored in the aura variable Available, you can totally send an hardcoded Id (which I do not recommend at all ;) )